# Identities for Matrix Exponent and Jacobi's formula

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

There is a neat matrix identity

$$\det(e^A) =e^{\operatorname{tr}(A)}$$

for a complex square matrix $A$, which follows from [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).

I wonder whether there are similar identities for the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of an exponent of a matrix:

$$X=\operatorname{perm}(e^A)$$

Comment: At the very least $X$ will not be of the form $e^{\varphi(A)}$, since $perm(e^A)$ can be $0$, for instance when $e^A$ is a $45$ degree rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$.